# PHP-font-lib must either be installed via composer or copied to lib/php-font-lib

Tags: php, dompdf

i'm trying to convert some html to pdf. 
After some google search i find [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) but when i try to convert i retrieve

```
PHP-font-lib must either be installed via composer or copied to lib/php-font-lib
```

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
require 'pdf/dompdf.php';
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

How can i solve? Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Dompdf moved recently to [Github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf), and we also added Composer support. For this, we removed the reference to the required external library [php-font-lib](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib).

Note: If you are using composer to install dompdf (and [php-font-lib](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib)), you need to put `define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", false);` in dompdf_config.custom.inc.php.  This will then allow composer to autoload [php-font-lib](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib) which is installed through dompdf's composer.json file.  Otherwise, you may still get an error.  (See this [issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/636))

If you are not using composer and want to use the latest edition of dompdf with this library: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505929/3854385))

- Get the latest dompdf release from [Github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases) and extract it into a directory.
- Download the library release also from [Github](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/releases)
- Create the dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/ directory.
- In the zip file, take the contents of the src/FontLib/ folder and paste that into your newly created directory.

Comment: Please note that not everyone knows what composer or PHP-font-lib is. So adding some more information to that error message would be really helpfull. ;)

Comment: Sorry for this, I should have been more verbose.

Comment: Copied the php-font-lib from the above linked 0.6 beta 3 and it worked like a charm. Cheers :)

Comment: This is still an issue I think. When not downloading via composer. It should be added to requirements info or installation info.

Comment: how to start from the scratch? I've made their script example works but I wanted to create my own. I haven't seen yet the tutorial for this, any link will help. Thanks

Comment: **Please notice** I ran into this answer but it didn't work for me. It seems that when the answer was written - the `php-font-lib` version was 0.2.2, using 0.4 won't solve it. Use 0.2.2 (https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/releases/tag/0.2.2)

Comment: Installing php-font-lib in Drupal 7 to be used by the print module 7.2.0 looks for version 0.2.2 file layout - 0.4 gives class not found

Comment: Also wanted to note that I had to download php-font-lib version 0.2.2 and extract the entire contents into /php-font-lib/ folder.

Comment: I had to change autoload.inc.php to change lib to vendor/phenx/ to the library paths.

Answer (score 2):

While my edit is being reviewed, I'll post the details here for the latest dompdf 0.6.1

If you are using composer to install dompdf (and php-font-lib), you need to put `define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", false);` in dompdf_config.custom.inc.php.  This will then allow composer to autoload php-font-lib which is installed through dompdf's composer.json file.  Otherwise, you may still get an error.  (See this Issue #636)

If you are not using composer and want to use the latest edition of dompdf, you will need to manually install php-font-lib: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505929/3854385)

- Get the latest dompdf release from [Github](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases) and extract it into a directory.
- Download the library release also from [Github](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/releases)
- Create the dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/ directory.
- In the zip file, take the contents of the src/FontLib/ folder and paste that into your newly created directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick, to avoid the change of automated downloaded files from Composer, is define the `DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD` and after reload the config file:

```
// Disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
require_once CONFIG_DIR . 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

$dompdf = new \DOMPDF;
```