# HOW TO: convert HTML to PDF with PHP/DOMpdf?

Tags: php

I need your help to fix this:

My current code is this:

```
<?php 
      require_once '../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
      use Dompdf\Dompdf;

      $dompdf = new Dompdf();
      $html = 'Insert full HTML content';
      $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
      $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
      $dompdf->render();
      $dompdf->stream("codexworld",array("Attachment"=>0));
?>
```

This is the error a get:
[image]

**Why if I have exactly the same code like the basic example, am I getting this error? What am I missing? I don't find in my folder the Autoloader.php, where do I have to get that file?**

Comment: Could you share the link to the example you're trying to follow?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: It's listed in the requirements section. Composer should grab the dependencies `composer require dompdf/dompdf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well apparently it's an issue after domPdf has moved to Github. It seems that php-font-lib library doesn't exist. So one solution is to manually download it:

- Go to https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib and download the library.
- In the zip file, take the contents of the src/FontLib/ folder and paste that into the folder lib/php-font-lib.

or you can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431905/php-font-lib-must-either-be-installed-via-composer-or-copied-to-lib-php-font-lib)

Comment: thank you, it works... after i did that, displayed another similar error but with other folder. i fixed it as the same way 

    require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/html5lib/Parser.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/Autoloader.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/php-svg-lib/src/autoload.php';

now i could convert a simple text to PDF